# Unable to link Invoice with Product Prices

Tags: sql, sql-server

Linking Invoice Options with Raw Material Prices (History table)

I am unable to use the Invoice i.DateSent in the second last line of the following query as I'm getting the following error. Also, if there is a better way to design the database / tables based, please let me know or if you any resources I should look up to make my concepts stronger. Thanks!

Error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "i.DateSent" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
The multi-part identifier "i.DateSent" could not be bound.
```

Query:

```
SELECT i.InvoiceID, i.DateSent, io.InvoiceOptionID, i.Customer, RawMaterialA.Name AS RawMaterialA, RawMaterialA.Price AS PriceA, RawMaterialB.Name AS RawMaterialB, RawMaterialB.Price AS PriceB
FROM InvoiceOption io
FULL JOIN Invoice i ON io.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 rm.RawMaterialID, rm.Name, rmp.Price, rmp.EffectiveDate
    FROM RawMaterial rm
    LEFT JOIN RawMaterialPrice rmp ON rm.RawMaterialID = rmp.RawMaterialID AND i.DateSent > rmp.EffectiveDate
) AS RawMaterialA ON io.RawMaterialAID = RawMaterialA.RawMaterialID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 rm.RawMaterialID, rm.Name, rmp.Price, rmp.EffectiveDate
    FROM RawMaterial rm
    LEFT JOIN RawMaterialPrice rmp ON rm.RawMaterialID = rmp.RawMaterialID AND i.DateSent > rmp.EffectiveDate
) AS RawMaterialB ON io.RawMaterialBID = RawMaterialB.RawMaterialID
```

My desired result

```
InvoiceID   DateSent    InvoiceOptionID Customer    RawMaterialA    PriceA  RawMaterialB    PriceB
1   2023-12-01  101 Customer A  Material X  50.00   Material Y  30.00
1   2023-12-01  102 Customer A  Material X  50.00   Material Z  20.00
```

Context:
Suppose I have a table Invoice which can have multiple options in InvoiceOption Table. The InvoiceOption depends on 2 types raw material A and B. But a raw material price can change and an old invoice should be able to check the price of the raw material used for. For this I'm using the EffectiveDate of RawMaterialPrice and DateSent of Invoice to join the InvoiceOption and RawMaterialPrice tables based on the following condition: (get the first price where Invoice.DateSent > RawMaterialPrice.EffectiveDate). The tables to generate the data and script is given below:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice (
    InvoiceID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Customer NVARCHAR(255),
    DateSent DATE,
    DateCreated DATE
);

-- Sample data
INSERT INTO Invoice (InvoiceID, Customer, DateSent, DateCreated)
VALUES
    (1, 'Customer A', '2023-12-01', '2023-11-28');

CREATE TABLE InvoiceOption (
    InvoiceOptionID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    InvoiceID INT,
    RawMaterialAID INT,
    RawMaterialBID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (InvoiceID) REFERENCES Invoice(InvoiceID)
);

-- Sample data
INSERT INTO InvoiceOption (InvoiceOptionID, InvoiceID, RawMaterialAID, RawMaterialBID)
VALUES
    (101, 1, 101, 102),
    (102, 1, 101, 103);

CREATE TABLE RawMaterial (
    RawMaterialID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    Category NVARCHAR(50)
);

-- Sample data
INSERT INTO RawMaterial (RawMaterialID, Name, Category)
VALUES
    (101, 'Material X', 'Metal'),
    (102, 'Material Y', 'Wood'),
    (103, 'Material Z', 'Wood');

CREATE TABLE RawMaterialPrice (
    RawMaterialPriceID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    RawMaterialID INT,
    Price DECIMAL(10, 2),
    EffectiveDate DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (RawMaterialID) REFERENCES RawMaterial(RawMaterialID)
);

-- Sample data
INSERT INTO RawMaterialPrice (RawMaterialPriceID, RawMaterialID, Price, EffectiveDate)
VALUES
    (1001, 101, 50.00, '2023-11-01'),
    (1002, 102, 30.00, '2023-11-01'),
    (1003, 103, 20.00, '2023-11-01'),
    (1004, 103, 10.00, '2023-10-01');
```

I tried asking Bing chat and understood i.DateSent might be out of scope in the joins I created but was unable to generate a valid answer.

Comment: You cannot make references to objects in the outer scope inside a derived table. If you need to do that, you would need to use `APPLY`, rather than a `JOIN`, or move the expressions to the `ON` for the `JOIN` to the derived table.

Comment: A JOINed subquery doesn't have access to outside tables inside itself. What you're looking for is OUTER APPLY. This allows you to properly use TOP as well.

Comment: Also a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is generally the sign of a flaw; the row(s) you get returned will be completely arbitrary and *could* be different *every time* you run the query.

Comment: Thank you Thomas and siggemannen! It kind of fixed the problem but not completely, I guess the ON clause doesn't work on OUTER APPLY so I changed to WHERE but I still couldn't manage to fix the second OUTER APPLY (as you may have noticed I have 2 Left Joins refering to the same child table but the parent table takes different records RawMaterialA and RawMaterialB. How do I fix the second OUTER APPLY? (Error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OUTER'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want an `OUTER APPLY` as this allows you to use outer references in the derived table. The join condition needs to be pushed inside as a `WHERE`

```sql
SELECT
  i.InvoiceID,
  i.DateSent,
  io.InvoiceOptionID,
  i.Customer,
  RawMaterialA.Name AS RawMaterialA,
  RawMaterialA.Price AS PriceA,
  RawMaterialB.Name AS RawMaterialB,
  RawMaterialB.Price AS PriceB
FROM InvoiceOption io
JOIN Invoice i ON io.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      rm.RawMaterialID,
      rm.Name,
      rmp.Price,
      rmp.EffectiveDate
    FROM RawMaterial rm
    JOIN RawMaterialPrice rmp ON rm.RawMaterialID = rmp.RawMaterialID
    WHERE i.DateSent > rmp.EffectiveDate
      AND rm.RawMaterialID = io.RawMaterialAID
    ORDER BY rmp.EffectiveDate DESC
) AS RawMaterialA
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      rm.RawMaterialID,
      rm.Name,
      rmp.Price,
      rmp.EffectiveDate
    FROM RawMaterial rm
    JOIN RawMaterialPrice rmp ON rm.RawMaterialID = rmp.RawMaterialID
    WHERE i.DateSent > rmp.EffectiveDate
      AND rm.RawMaterialID = io.RawMaterialBID
    ORDER BY rmp.EffectiveDate DESC
) AS RawMaterialB;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/xn7zPZ61)

The reason for you using `FULL` and `LEFT` joins in some cases is not clear. They should probably be inner joins as noted.

I've also added an `ORDER BY` to make the results deterministic.

Comment: Thank you so much Charlie! I was using a Full Join to get an Invoice even if it doesn't have it doesn't have a InvoiceOption. Probably right join might be right for this as the other way round (Left Join with invoiceOption data only without Invoice Data) wont be possible because of Foreign key. And Left Join to get the Invoice Option detail even if it doesnt have a Material. Let me know if I'm wrong in understanding this and please let me know if you recommend any resources to get better at joins / designing tables. Hopefully the above design isnt too bad? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes correct, but the normal thing to do would be to put `Invoice` first and do a left-join. The left-join inside the subquery doesn't seem to make sense though, unless you expect there to be no price.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds much better. I expect RawMaterialA to always have a price but RawMaterialB is optional so no price so left join

Comment: Not quite the same. Is there a `RawMaterial` with no `RawMaterialPrice`? Or is it that `RawMaterialB` is null? If the former you need a left-join, if the latter you can rely on `OUTER APPLY` as opposed to `CROSS APPLY` to act like a left-join over the whole subquery.

Comment: Thanks and yup, the latter - RawMaterialB is null in Invoice but all rows in RawMaterial have atleast 1 row linking to RawMaterialPrice. Also, is it necessary to use the WHERE clause in OUTER APPLY as opposed to putting the conditions on the ON clause?

Comment: You can't use an `ON` in an `APPLY` as it's not actually a join. The subquery as a whole is "applied" to each row of the outer table(s). So the condition needs to go on the inside.